# Entity Framework: How to express a LIKE statement that contains [0-9]

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I would like to construct a LINQ query for use against an EF context that selected rows based on a LIKE condition.
As I understand you can get this behaviour using `.Contains()`. However, the LIKE I would like to include contains a number range:

```
LIKE 'LN[0-9]%'
```

for example...

How would I go about replicating this behaviour in a simple query?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Currently u can't use like in LINQ directly. U can use `StartsWith`, `Contains` or `EndsWith` that are translated to LIKE. Other solution is using 'Where' overide with 'string' like this:
    Where("something LIKE 'LN[0-9]%'")

[Here is example](http://dobbydotnet.blogspot.com/2008/10/linq-to-entities-like-operator.html)

Answer (score 1):

try StartsWith like so:

```
var query = Cities.Where(city => city.Code.StartsWith("LN[0-9]"));
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities will add escape and treat [0-9] as part of string

Answer (score 0):

This is a regex problem ([0-9] is a regex nomenclature).  I suggest you try something like this:

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex("LN[0-9]");

var matches = Cities.Where(c => myRegex.IsMatch(c.Field));
```

A crude example but should get you started.

Comment: It's worth noting that the [tag:entity-framework] doesn't support this directly. See @Piotr's answer. Also, note had the OP been using [tag:linq-to-sql] then he could have used `SqlMethods`.